why there's no output file
i try to find the answer but they are almost 6 years ago or older.then i see the issue on github. i try to custom a target following github but failed
i get the dll file from nuget package and add to unity as a plugin, then i can use nlog but without any output.
below is my nlog.config
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd NLog.xsd"
      autoReload="true"
      throwExceptions="false"
      internalLogLevel="Off" internalLogFile="c:\temp\nlog-internal.log">

  <targets>

    <target name="UnityLog" type="UnityLog" fileName="c:\log.txt" 
    layout = "[${longdate}] ${level}(${logger}): ${message} |${all-event-properties}: ${exception:format=tostring}"/>

  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="UnityLog" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="UnityLog" />
  </rules>

</nlog>

and the definition of target
using NLog;
using NLog.Layouts;
using NLog.Targets;
using UnityEngine;

[Target("UnityLog")]
public class UnityLog : TargetWithLayout
{
    protected override void Write(LogEventInfo logEvent)
    {
        Name = "UnityLog";
        var msg = Layout.Render(logEvent);
        Debug.Log(msg);
    }
}


You are specifying fileName="c:\log.txt" but your custom UnityLog-target doesn't have a FileName-property.
If you want output to both UnityEngine.Debug and also file-path, then you should setup 2 NLog-targets:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd NLog.xsd"
      autoReload="true"
      throwConfigExceptions="true"
      internalLogLevel="Off" internalLogFile="c:\temp\nlog-internal.log">
  <targets>

    <target name="UnityLog" type="UnityLog"
    layout = "[${longdate}] ${level}(${logger}): ${message} |${all-event-properties}: ${exception:format=tostring}"/>

    <target name="FileLog" type="File" fileName="C:\Temp\Log.txt"
    layout = "[${longdate}] ${level}(${logger}): ${message} |${all-event-properties}: ${exception:format=tostring}"/>

  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="UnityLog, FileLog" />
  </rules>

</nlog>

Notice that the C-Root-Drive is usually off-limits, so changed from C:\Log.txt to C:\Temp\Log.txt.
